# Double first column in google Timeline Chart

Tags: charts, timeline

we're using Google's timeline chart and we need it to look sort of like this:
**desired output**
[image: desired output]

but Google Charts won't allow more than one column at the beginning of each track.

**current output**
[image: current output]

Is there any way to have two separated columns? Or another chart library that supports this format?